# Is it possible to cause an object in Blender v. 2.79b to produce a sound whenever it is struck?

Tags: animation, audio

While creating a 3d model of a guitar, I have been trying to figure out how to make the strings vibrate ***and*** produce a sound when struck.  I am not sure what to do to get it to work.  I have looked online several times for tutorials on how I might get this to work, but without success.  Can you help me?  NOTE: I know how you can add audio through the Movie Clip Editor.  This is not what I am looking for.

P.S. I request that the community tag this item with any other relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a cylinder as a string and shape keys to move it up and down:
[image]
[image]

Create a new Shape Key to move up and down the string:

[image]

Then move the string up with Proportional Editing turned on:

[image]
[image]

Allow the shape key to get a minimum value of -1 to let the string move down:

[image]

Then animate the scale of the object:

[image]

Bake the sound file to the onto the scale animation curve:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Next bake the animation curve:

[image]

Copy the keyframes from the scale animation to the shape key animation:

[image]
[image]

Delete the scale, location and rotation keyframes (don't forget to set the scale back to 1.0 in all axes after this):

[image]

Finally, add some noise modifier to the animation curve to move the string up and down:

[image]
[image]